# Why is views method not being invoked?

Tags: python, django, url

I have a web directory with `urls.py` in a directory (RazorWare_Web) as follows:

```
from RazorWare_Web.views import home

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url('/', home.index, name="index"),
                       url(r'^razorware/', include("RazorCRM_App.urls")),
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       )
```

So in my browser, `http://localhost:8000/razorware` navigates to the `home` view's `index()` method. I'm a little confused by this. I would expect `http://localhost:8000/` would navigate to `home`. Instead this produces a url not found error page.

Aside from that, the real problem (and I suspect it is related to the above) exists when I perform a `$.getJSON` call from my HTML page. First, the actual app exists under the sibling directory, RazorCRM_App, with the following:

```
from RazorCRM_App.views import queries

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'query_locale', queries.query_locales, name="query_locales"),
]
```

When I execute the following script:

```
function query_locale_by_zip(){
    var post_code = txt_postal.val();
    $.getJSON("query_locale", {post_code: post_code}, function(result){
        console.log("[APP] query locale for: " + post_code + " [returned: " + result.success + "]")
    });
}
```

... the `queries.query_locales` method is not being called. However, I do get the following output from the console:

> [25/Feb/2015 15:20:51] "GET /razorware/query_locale?post_code=9
>   HTTP/1.1" 200
>   [25/Feb/2015 15:20:51] "GET
>   /razorware/query_locale?post_code=92 HTTP/1.1" 200
>   [25/Feb/2015
>   15:20:51] "GET /razorware/query_locale?post_code=920 HTTP/1.1" 200
>   [25/Feb/2015 15:20:52] "GET
>   /razorware/query_locale?post_code=9205 HTTP/1.1" 200
>   [25/Feb/2015 15:20:52] "GET /razorware/query_locale?post_code=92058
>   HTTP/1.1" 200

I might understand if there was a message stating that the url could not be found. But this just seems odd.

Using Django version 1.7.1 and Python 3.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root url should look like `url(r'^$', home.index, name="index")` and your query_locale url should look like `url(r'^query_locale/$', queries.query_locales, name="query_locales")`.

[url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/) has broad documentation about how urls work.

Comment: Thanks ...I'm still trying to get through the docs for url dispatcher.

Comment: You are welcome. You will see, once you have an urls file working example, it will be the same for all your incoming projects.